# Lowercase all the associative array keys without foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, lowercase

I have this array which is held by this variable:

```
$get_multiple_role_will_redirect = isset($_POST['multiple_role_will_redirect']) ? $_POST['multiple_role_will_redirect'] : 0;

Array
(
    [Administrator] => 
    [Editor] => 
    [Author] => 
    [Contributor] => 
    [Subscriber] => 
    [Shop_manager] => 
    [Shop_accountant] => 
    [Shop_worker] => 
    [Shop_vendor] => 
    [Edd_subscriber] => 
    [Customer] => 
)
```

Now, I want to lowercase all the keys. To do that I am doing foreach like that:

```
$multiple_role_will_redirect = [];
foreach($get_multiple_role_will_redirect as $key => $value) {
    $key = strtolower($key);
    $multiple_role_will_redirect[$key] = $value;
}
```

My question is, Is there any other way without `foreach` loop to **lowercase** the array **key**?

I have checked with :

```
array_filter($get_multiple_role_will_redirect, 'strtolower');
```

But it's not lowercase the array key.

Comment: Why don't you want to use foreach?

Comment: Just want to know is there any better way

Comment: I think there is no way to do this without loop the array.

Comment: check the @Vimal answer

Comment: it will also loop the array.

Comment: check my answer, the source code of `array_change_key_case`, there is also `foreach` in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `array_change_key_case` function works for you .

```
$age=array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
print_r(array_change_key_case($age,CASE_LOWER));
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_change_key_case.asp

Comment: I see. It will work but is there any way to sanitize the value without for each if I want?

Comment: I know but I am asking that if I want to sanitize the value then is there any other function without the help of `foreach`?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to show there is no possible to make it without loop. For the accepted answer's `array_change_key_case` also has loop implementation with `ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL`

Refer to the source code of `array_change_key_case` [src: array_change_key_case](https://github.com/colinodell/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c)

```
PHP_FUNCTION(array_change_key_case)
{
    zval *array, *entry;
    zend_string *string_key;
    zend_string *new_key;
    zend_ulong num_key;
    zend_long change_to_upper=0;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 2)
        Z_PARAM_ARRAY(array)
        Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL
        Z_PARAM_LONG(change_to_upper)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END();

    array_init_size(return_value, zend_hash_num_elements(Z_ARRVAL_P(array)));

    ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(Z_ARRVAL_P(array), num_key, string_key, entry) {
        if (!string_key) {
            entry = zend_hash_index_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(return_value), num_key, entry);
        } else {
            if (change_to_upper) {
                new_key = php_string_toupper(string_key);
            } else {
                new_key = php_string_tolower(string_key);
            }
            entry = zend_hash_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(return_value), new_key, entry);
            zend_string_release_ex(new_key, 0);
        }

        zval_add_ref(entry);
    } ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array by combining the lowercased keys from your old with the values from your old.  Here replacing the original.

```
<?php

$items = 
[
    'Foo' => 'hello',
    'Bar' => 'world'
];

$items = array_combine(
    array_map('strtolower', array_keys($items)), 
    $items
);

var_export($items);
```

Output:

```
array (
    'foo' => 'hello',
    'bar' => 'world',
  )
```